# 504 gateway time-out nginx reverse proxy

Tags: linux, nginx, centos

Всем доброго дня.
Прошу помощи не от недостатка гугления в крови... Попробовал множество вариантов, но решение проблемы не нашел
Стоит reverse proxy на nginx. Через него передаются большие пакеты jsone, при запросе которых Nginx возвращает 504-ю.
Сейчас конфиг выглядит примерно так

```
proxy_connect_timeout 3000;
proxy_send_timeout 3000;
proxy_read_timeout 3000;
send_timeout 3000;
client_header_timeout 3000;
client_body_timeout 3000;
fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
client_max_body_size 3200m;
fastcgi_buffers 8 128000k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 128000k;


server_name *;
#return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
root /var/www/$server_name;
access_log /var/log/nginx/*.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/*.log;
location / {
proxy_set_header Host *;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_pass http://*;
```

Если у кого-нибудь есть идеи или догадки, помогите пожалуйста...

Comment: А без nginx эти большие пакеты идут нормально?

Comment: 504 возможно говорит что не в nginx проблема, а там, куда проксируются запросы, другими словами стоит понять реально ли происходит проксирование и если да, то обратить внимание на сервис адресат

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Проблема оказалась вообще в другом. Сам конфиг написан правильно.
Если вкратце, другой администратор сделал копию моей прокси и передавал пакеты через него, поэтому все мои изменения ни на что не влияли :D 
Вопрос закрыт